# Is there a name for when a lead part keeps repeating the same short melody while the rest of the band/orchestra/etc changes behind them?

Tags: terminology, solos

It's one of my favourite musical devices and can make a really great impact.

I think I can best demonstrate this with a couple of songs on youtube.

> 1) ...And You Will Know Us by the Trail of Dead - "Will You Smile Again for Me":

For the first minute and a half we have a single 1-bar guitar part (ie an ostinato or riff) which stays constant while the rest of the band work through a chord sequence and various other changes.

From about a minute till 1:30 there's also a synth riff which stays the same while some more changes happen in the background.

> 2) Buzzocks - "Boredom"

1:20 to 1:45

Perhaps the simplest possible example of this ever made: the lead guitar just plays the same two notes over and over again while the rest of the band go through various chord changes.

These are the best parts of the tracks for me - is there a name for this musical device?

EDIT: to address the "duplicate" suggestion:  I don't think this is a duplicate of that other question: that question is (I think) talking about something within an ostinato that stays the same when the rest of the ostinato changes. So for example when a guitarist might play a sequence of four two-bar riffs, and within each riff the first half-bar is the same set of notes. So it's related, but not the same.

EDIT 2: another example: the piano part from 4:55 till 5:52, in Clubbed To Death by Rob Dougan

, which stays the same while everything else repeats the same chord progression several times.

Comment: I dunno!  "Hi Fly" and "One Note Samba" come to mind, too.

Comment: @BruceFields mind posting up some youtube links with the time where it happens in the song?

Comment: vamping would be one term for incessantly repeated bits

Comment: @thrig i thought "vamping" is when a band keeps playing a simple repeated part behind the vocalist, usually while they do something spontaneous (like talk to the crowd).    I just checked and it can also be used to mean "jam over the top of something", but what I'm talking about is sort of the opposite:  the lead part stays the same while the rest changes.

Comment: You said it yourself, it's an *ostinato*, "a motif or phrase that persistently repeats in the same musical voice, usually at the same pitch" ([wikipedia ostinato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostinato))

Comment: @joseem that doesn't get the key aspect across though, that what everyone else is playing changes while the ostinato stays the same.

Comment: I don't think that ostinato means that all instruments are doing an...ostinato. One instrument or voice is doing an ostinato, the others, presumably, are not. But maybe someone comes up with a more specific word...

Comment: @Dave - i don't think so - that question is (I think) talking about something **within** an ostinato that stays the same when the rest of the ostinato changes.  So for example when a guitarist might play a sequence of four two-bar riffs, and within each riff the first half-bar is the same set of notes.  So it's related, but not the same I think.

Comment: The ostinato *is* the part that stays the same despite the context changing.

Comment: https://popmusictheory.com/what-is-ostinato/ esp. examples 1 and 4

Comment: @Dave - i know it's an ostinato, but it's a particular usage of an ostinato that i'm after. Just calling it an ostinato on it's own isn't specific enough.  On that link, the first one (Smashing Pumpkins) **does** actually do what I'm talking about, but the others don't really.   So yes, the ostinato is the part that stays the same while the context changes, in my examples, but there are other ostinatos that **do not** do this, and so the word ostinato on its own is inadequate to describe it.

Comment: Perhaps it's just called "a short ostinato with a chord progression behind it".

Comment: "mind posting up some youtube links" for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uugcu0cYvZc 0:08--0:19, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDzWWmscbt8 0:17-0:28.